# Most efficient way to select a set of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've always used class names to select sets of related elements. e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="checkbox_set_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="checkbox_set_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" class="checkbox_set_1">

$('.checkbox_set_1').filter(':checked') ...
```

I do this because I know jQuery can delegate to `document.getElementsByClassName` which should be pretty fast. However, adding classes to all the elements I want to *select* but not *style* seems kind of dirty. Isn't there some overhead when the browser has to check `checkbox_set_1` against its stylesheet to determine if my checkboxes need styling? Plus, there's some risk of accidental styling if I haven't named my classes nicely.

Is there a better way to select elements that doesn't rely on an attribute meant for styling, without giving up the performance benefits? Or more specifically, is there an attribute other than `class` (used for styling) and `id` (limited to a single element) that the browser will optimize queries for?

There are many other attributes to pick from, including `data-*` attributes, but I don't think the browser optimizes lookups on anything other than `id` and `class`, does it?

Comment: Hate to say this but question is a bit broad. Highly improbable you wouldn't have other structure within a form or table or whatever repeating elements might exist, and you won't likely be searching many times a second for this. For simplicity could use `$('.mainContainer input:checkbox:checked')` and likely never notice performance issues

Comment: @charlietfl It's unlikely to be a bottleneck, sure, but it doesn't make much difference to me if I write `$('#xxx')` or `$('.yyy')` or `$('a[b=c]')` -- I'm just looking for a rule of thumb so that I have something to default to. Relying on the structure itself seems more prone to error -- I might move these checkboxes in or out of a table, or nest them deeper in the DOM or what have you; I'd prefer an attribute directly on the element.

Comment: ok...so if you are likely to move them, probably move a wrapper for them also ... selector in prior comment would get you past classes on each

Comment: Give them names? Give them a parent that is common?

Comment: Also pretty hard to ignore either  structure or some sort of classes , not necessarily classes on each input

Comment: Older article, but nice overview http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/

Comment: @charlietfl Still not a good solution. `.mainContainer` is used for styling, now you're using it to target specific elements -- the exact problem I was trying to avoid. Moreover, adding more wrappers or moving the wrapper is the same problem -- why wouldn't I just put the class on the elements themselves at this point? In fact, you've made the problem bigger because you're suggesting I use classes that I already have, classes with styling. So now not only am I affecting my selection, I'm changing the appearance of my site.

Comment: @epascarello Name is one possibility. My question is then do I use `$('[name=xxx]')`, `$('input[name=xxx]')` or what? What is the efficiency trade-off of each? Is using name as a selector as efficient as class?

Comment: not at all ... is common practice to use classes for structure not just style . Some projects even use special prefixes for structure based classes vs style classes. Consider a UI with lots of elements and you need to apply lots of event handlers...have to isolate various elements somehow

Comment: @charlietfl Now we're getting somewhere. You're saying I should just suck it up and use classes for structure, even though they were built for style. That I can live with if it's still the best method to go.

Comment: However, I'm still waiting for someone to tell me if the browser indexes/optimizes anything other than "class" and "id".

Comment: absolutely.... would say you are prematurely optimizing. As for attributes they aren't nearly as efficient as class for dom searches. Although `form.name` is pretty quick but how many of those checkboxes will have same name?

Comment: @charlietfl If I'm prematurely optimizing, then I should use `<input data-inputSet="checkboxes">` and `$('*').filter(function() { $(this).data('inputSet')==='checkboxes'; })` because I know `data-inputSet` is *not* used for anything other than my intended purpose, which is to select a very specific set of elements. In this way there is zero potential for a class name clash, zero chance of accidentally submitting form elements I didn't intend, and zero effect on the state of my input. I can even make a function to do this for me, so it will be concise. Yet, this isn't a good idea, is it?

Comment: Run tests and find out http://jsperf.com/. Are your having a case of [premature optimization](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil/)?

Comment: not arguing against the data attributes as they are very useful. Still wouldn't remove human error of placing wrong one there though, that's what testing is for

Comment: @epascarello http://jsperf.com/jquery-select-performance The slowest method is 270x slower than the fastest method. I'd say that's significant enough for concern, particularly when the data method is measured in the hundreds.

Comment: `$(*)` is defintiely slow, means checking every element in page and bypassing faster native dom methods... note that jQuery uses different query engines also depending on type of selector used

Comment: @charlietfl Right, but I'd have to check *every* element if I wanted to use a custom attribute like that, wouldn't I? And yeah, I know jQuery delegates to different native methods -- I mentioned that in my question. It's a big part of my question.

Comment: no...you pass the attribute as part of selector and let the query method find them. TagName ranks high in indexing

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't there some overhead when the browser has to check checkbox_set_1
>   against its stylesheet to determine if my checkboxes need styling?

Styling isn't determined that way. The browser doesn't take each attributes of an element and look for rules that apply, instead it looks through the rules once and determine which ones applies to the element.

If you are concerned with adding classes to a lot of elements, you can use selectors that make better use of the document structure, for example setting a class on the element containing the checkboxes and use something like `$('.CheckboxContainer :checked')`.

That might not be quite as efficient as setting classes on every element that you want to target, but in most cases the difference is far from noticable. You shouldn't bother too much about efficient selectors until it's an actual problem. After all, you are using jQuery because it's convenient, not to get the best performance.

Comment: So you're saying that adding unused classes to elements has no overhead because they won't exist in the stylesheet, ergo the browser never performs an element lookup? Adding lots of classes isn't so much the concern, its using them for their non-intended purpose, and potential name clashes within the stylesheet. ReactJS, for example, adds a `ref` attribute which is much better suited for this purpose.

Comment: @Mark: Naturally there is an overhread because there is more data in the element to consider, but it's very small. You would need to add a whole bunch of classes to every element before it would be a problem. Even if classes were introduced to be used with style sheets, they are not limited to that use. A lot of things has happened since style sheets were added, and lots of things are not used as originally intended. CSS selectors for example were not originally intended for selecting elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it behaves analouge to the "Marker-Interface in java" and you will find the [anti-pattern-description of Tom Butler](https://r.je/empty-interfaces-bad-practice.html).

If you have a form around, you could use [elements](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_form_elements.asp) (but you must filter other elements) this is faster than calling a method like "getElementsByClassName".

Example

```js
var lst = jQuery(document.foo.elements);
document.write(lst.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="foo">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" form="bar" />
</form>
```

Comment: no idea what the java classes reference link has to do with html classes or this question

Comment: He uses css-classes without styling like java-interfaces without methods.Its the same misuse as Tom said by "indended purpose".

Comment: that's all fine and good to say but in the real world what do you propose to isolate specific elements? Convention for years has been to use common class for common elements. Your example in answer is not very universal

Comment: AFAIK the question is: "Is there a better way to select elements that doesn't rely on an attribute meant for styling, without giving up the performance benefits?". As long as there are no other specifications, its a answer.

Comment: I was hoping for something more generic than limited to form elements, and something more specific than "you can filter other elements" (how?).

Comment: @Mark Well, you could filter using the html5-attribute "form", see my edit. Give a element a different form-name and here we filter.